# how to make Header In android

Tags: android

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/contact_relMainHeader"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dip"
        android:background="#16A180"
        android:padding="5dp" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/contact_btnMenu"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
            android:background="@drawable/scrol" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/contact_btnLogout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
            android:background="@drawable/lock" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dip"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/contact_btnLogout"
            android:background="@drawable/centertext"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

I need to create header Like given Image.

[image]

But i am Unable to set i tried But Not Looking Eject image .

This is my Screen :

[image]

i have tried much but i am unable to achieved eject like given image

Comment: Just stop it. You are building an iOS design for Android. Please read the stile guides of Android and build with that knowledge a new App.

Comment: What do you mean by *eject*?

Comment: See header compare with my Header its coming Eject like this i want make it eject like this

Comment: @rekire you are absolutely right dude. why this people always copied design from iOS?

Comment: @SimplePlan the reason is simple the Deciders mostly use Apple devices and also of payed apps you get faster money. Android users simply buy less often apps. With that reasons in mind the iOS app is designed first that they think hey there was a platform called Android: We need to support it, the design is already done so let's find somebody who implement it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to achieve this, your images are streched so don't use `background` value. Instead, use `src` and don't use `Button`, use `ImageView`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/contact_relMainHeader"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dip"
        android:background="#16A180"
        android:padding="5dp" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/contact_btnMenu"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
            android:src="@drawable/scrol" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/contact_btnLogout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
            android:src="@drawable/lock" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/centertext"
             />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: can you upload one screen shot? how this layout looks?

Comment: I don't have the images so can't exacly show the askers screen. I used custom images to check if it is what he wanted.

Answer (score 1):

```
// try this way,hope this will help you...

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/contact_lnrMainHeader"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:background="#16A180"
    android:padding="10dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/contact_btnMenu"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1">
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/contact_btnLogout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"/>

</LinearLayout>
```